# Errror reading from remote server returned by /jenkins

Tags: apache, jenkins, mod-proxy

I am using Jenkins and currently Jenkins is running fine in the background; however, when i am trying to access Jenkins using browser the homepage of Jenkins is not accessible.  When I access it I get "Error reading from remote server ( 502 )".  Has anyone encountered such an issue? What could be the workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did restart of iptables post which I have seen the issue to be resolved.

service iptables restart

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove proxy: `export http_proxy="" && curl http://servername:portnumber/destinationpath/`

or use https instead of http or vice-versa ( check which port is your jenkins running on )

Is it running on apache/nginx/whatever? Restart that. Restart Jenkins once more. Check the server configuration regarding those.